# How to set Rails application to Production mode? I'm using capistrano

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capistrano

How to set Rails application to Production mode?  I'm using capistrano

On my server, doing a rails console shows its in development mode (puts RAILS_ENV)

Answer (score 1):

It really depends on the software you're using to serve your production site.  For example, [Passenger](http://www.modrails.com/) sets the environment to production [by default](http://www.modrails.com/documentation/Users%20guide%20Apache.html#rails_env).

You should investigate the configuration for your production application server.

Comment: Yes, this has nothing to do with capistrano, but your web server.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you include

```
ENV['RAILS_ENV'] ||= 'production'
```

in your `environment.rb` file.